# max and min terms question i think

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

Im having trouble figuring out what the dsummation refers to. I think it is max terms but i dont know.

Answer (score 2):

The d() just means "don't care." You can look [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/dont-care-condition-in-k-map-in-digital-electronics) for an example of its use.

The \$\sum\$ symbol is used when specifying minterms and talking about the ***sum of products***.

The \$\Pi\$ symbol is used when specifying maxterms and talking about the ***product of sums***.

Suppose this table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{States} & \text{Output}\\\hline\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  A & B & C & D\\\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&1\\
  0&0&1&1\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&1&0&0\\
  0&1&0&1\\
  0&1&1&1\\
  0&1&1&0\\
  1&1&0&0\\
  1&1&0&1\\
  1&1&1&1\\
  1&1&1&0\\
  1&0&0&0\\
  1&0&0&1\\
  1&0&1&1\\
  1&0&1&0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  Y \\\\
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    x\\
    x\\
    x\\
    x\\
    0\\
    x\\
    x\\
    x\\
    x\\
    x\\
    x\\
    1\\
    x
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

Then you could write \$Y=\sum m\left(0, 11\right)+\sum d\left(2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15\right)\$ in minterm notation. (Maxterm notation would use \$\Pi\, M\left(\right)\$.)